# Flex: How to resize DisplayObject to fit panel in Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3, uicomponents

I am trying to attach some of my actionscript class, inherited from Sprite, to my Flex application by attaching it to a UIComponent, then add UIComponent to a panel. However, the size of my Sprite class appears to be larger than the panel. So, I try to resize it using DisplayObject.scale property, but I need to know the size of my container. Since I try to make my code reusable, I figure that I should let my Sprite class handle the resize by getting it via its parent property (let's say, I can resize it by set

this.scaleX = this.parent.Width/this.width   or something like this)

However, my Sprite class's parent, which is the UIComponent, has width/height of 0.
So, my question is:
1) Is there any better way to resize DisplayObject class to fit its container when attached to Flex object?
2) If you know, why my UIComponent's size remain 0 and my DisplayObject still appears at its full size?

Here's my code, using Flash Builder 4:

```
private var loader:Loader = new Loader();
private function testLoader():void {
  var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/welcome.png");
  loader.load(urlRequest);
  loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoaderLoadComplete);
}

private function onLoaderLoadComplete(e:Event):void {
  loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoaderLoadComplete);
  var ui : UIComponent = new UIComponent();
  ui.addChild(loader);
  panelTest.addElement(ui);
  trace("ui.width = " + ui.width);
  trace("ui.height = " + ui.height);
  trace("loader.width = " + loader.width);
  trace("loader.height = " + loader.height);
  trace("panelTest.width = " + panelTest.width);
  trace("panelTest.height = " + panelTest.height);
}
```

And this is the result when run:

```
ui.width = 0
ui.height = 0
loader.width = 571
loader.height = 411
panelTest.width = 480
panelTest.height = 320
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I think it's the other way around: the parent should set the child element size while rendering. You can override the *updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number,      unscaledHeight:Number)* method to set the size of your loader child. See [Advanced Visual Components in ActionScript](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_7.html).
2. I guess that the size of your *ui* is not really 0. The size is updated later after the layout and rendering process. So you have to wait for the layout to complete after adding a component to stage.

Comment: I have modified the code to trace after ui has been added to stage, like this:
private function onLoaderLoadComplete(e:Event):void {
  loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoaderLoadComplete);   
  ui.addChild(loader);
  ui.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,onUILoadComplete);
  panelTest.addElement(ui);
}

Comment: private function onUILoadComplete(e:Event):void {
  ui.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,onUILoadComplete);
  trace("ui.width = " + ui.width);
  trace("ui.height = " + ui.height);
  trace("loader.width = " + loader.width);
  trace("loader.height = " + loader.height);
  trace("panelTest.width = " + panelTest.width);
  trace("panelTest.height = " + panelTest.height);
}


The result still the same

Answer (score 0):

About the remaining 0, unfortunately is a known (grrr) problem: http://www.mail-archive.com/flexcoders@yahoogroups.com/msg39998.html

You can try to access it in a hacked way (using the mx_internal namespace): [get width of dynamically created custom uicomponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131486/flex-get-width-of-dynamically-created-custom-uicomponent)

Adding the sprite directly to the panel may also be helpful. This can be done by adding the loader to the panel's rawChildren: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?p=728034

Enjoy.